# How to filter dynamically nested list object java 8

Tags: java, java-8

How to filter dynamically nested list object java 8

Example:

```
class Items {
    List<Mobile> mobiles;
}

class Mobile{
    String mName;
    List<Plans> plans;
}

class Plans{
    String planId;
    String planName;
}
```

So, I have 3 mobiles (mobiles will be dynamic 3 or 4..etc) with multiple plans on each mobile device. How to dynamically filter common  plan for each mobile device ?

Example(P1-planId) :

```
Items:
    M1 - P1,P2,P3,P4
    M2 - P4,P5,P6,P1,P8,P2
    M3 - P7,P2,P4,P1,P8,P9,P10
```

Result:

```
Items:
    M1 - P1,P2,P4
    M2 - P1,P2,P4
    M3 - P1,P2,P4
```

Comment: You can start iterating with the first mobile and store all its plan to a list. Then while iterating on other mobiles from your input, **retainAll** those plans which are also a part of the current mobile you are iterating in the loop. You would be left only with plans common to all at the end.

Comment: Is there a reason why P4 isn't in the result set?

Comment: P4 also to be added M1 - P1,P2,P4 M2 - P1,P2,P4 M3 - P1,P2,P4

Answer (score 2):

A method inside `Items` to get all plans common to all mobiles might look like:

```
public List<Plan> getCommonPlans() {
    return mobiles.stream().flatMap(Mobile::streamPlans).distinct()
        .filter(p -> mobiles.stream().allMatch(m -> m.hasPlan(p)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

this assumes `Mobile.streamPlans` and `Mobile.hasPlan` methods which are pretty trivial.

A slightly different method, more efficient but perhaps not so intuitive, is to count the plans and filter for ones that have counts equal to number of mobiles:

```
    return mobiles.stream().flatMap(Mobile::streamPlans)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m, Collectors.counting())
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() == mobiles.size())
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

First, take plans of the first mobile and `retainAll` plans of mobiles from that list.

```
List<Plans> commonPlans = new ArrayList<>(mobiles.get(0).getPlans());
for (int i = 1; i < mobiles.size(); i++) {
  commonPlans.retainAll(mobiles.get(i).getPlans());
}
```

*Note:* Make sure you override `equals` and `hashCode` for `Plans` and check for empty mobiles list

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach would be to:

- stream all `Mobile`s,
- map each `Mobile` to its `List<Plan>`s
- create the union of all plans.

In code, this might look something like this:

```
HashSet<Plan> initialSet = new HashSet<>(mobiles.get(0).getPlans());
return mobiles.stream()
    .map(Mobile::getPlans)
    .map(HashSet<Plan>::new)
    .reduce(initialSet, (plan1, plan2) -> { 
        plan1.retainAll(plan2);
        return plan1;
    });
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/cUKZuY)