# Given n linked list containing integers, find the common elements between them and return the list

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I was asked this question in one of my recent interviews. I could not come up with a satisfactory answer within the given time.

Given N singly-linked lists containing integers, find the common elements or intersection points between them and return the list containing only the common elements.

Example:

**Input:**

list1 = [1, 3, 4, 5, 10, 3]

list2 = [1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 2]

list3 = [9, 11, 1, 4]

**Output:**

list = [1, 4]

**Note:** Please note that duplicate elements within the same list shall not be considered.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312068/how-to-filter-dynamically-nested-list-object-java-8/63312265

Comment: `Map<Integer,Set<Integer>>` looks very useful here where the set will hold list number. If the set size is `n`, bingo, it's a common element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lists implement [common `List` interface of the Collections framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), it can be implemented using `retainAll` method:

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 4, 5, 10, 3);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 2);
List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(9, 11, 1, 4);
        
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(list1);

Stream.of(list2, list3).forEach(result::retainAll);
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Maintain a **HashMap<Integer, Integer> List_Frequency** for storing frequency of lists in which that element is present.

**Step 2:** Traverse each list. While traversing again maintain another **HashMap<Integer, Integer> Visit**  to know that you are visiting an element in the list for the first time or not. So, that it leads to increment the HashMap List_Frequency only once.

**Step 3:** Traverse the HashMap List_Frequency to know which elements are visited N times.